# django form action on text input / scan

Tags: python, html, django

Hi I have a text input box like:

```
<div class="form-group">SCAN ORDERS : &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input id="scan_order" name="scan_order" type="text" placeholder="Scan" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

It is inside a form which already has action defined. I want to use this textbox with a barcode scanner. So how to bind this with a django view?

When data is scanned in this box, I want to pass that data to my django view.

My views.py:

```
def packOrders(request):
    oid_list = []
    form = forms.OrderItems(request.POST or None)
    api = APIMethods()
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'download_labels' in request.POST:
        list_of_ids = request.POST.getlist('po')
        for id in list_of_ids:
            oid_list.append(id)

        api.downloadShippingLabels(oid_list)
        file = open('shipping_labels.pdf', 'rb')
        response = HttpResponse(file, content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=shipping_labels.pdf"
        os.system('rm shipping_labels.pdf')
        return response

    elif request.method == 'POST' and 'mark_dispatch' in request.POST:
        list_of_ids = request.POST.getlist('po')
        for id in list_of_ids:
            oid_list.append(id)
        api.dispatchOrders(oid_list)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('orders'))
```

html form :

```
<form action="{% url 'packOrders' %}" method="POST">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                            <div class="pad-btm form-inline">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-sm-6 table-toolbar-left">
                                                        <button name="download_labels" id="download_labels" class="btn btn-purple btn-labeled fa">Download Labels</button>
                                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                        <button name="mark_dispatch" id="mark_dispatch" class="btn btn-purple btn-labeled fa">Mark Ready To Dispatch</button>


                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-6 table-toolbar-right">
                                                        <div class="form-group">SCAN ORDERS : &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                            <input name="scan_order" id="scan_order" type="text" placeholder="Scan" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                                                        </div>

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                                <table class="table table-striped">
                                                    <thead>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this, 'po')"></th>
                                                            <th>Order Id</th>
                                                            <th>Channel</th>
                                                            <th>Dispatch By Date</th>
                                                            <th>Amount</th>
                                                            <th>Status</th>
                                                            <th>Tracking Number</th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        {% for oid,oiid,dbd,stts,tp in pack_orders %}
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="po" value="{{oiid}}"></td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <div>
                                                                    <a class="btn-link" href="#">{{oid}}</a>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div>
                                                                    {{oiid}}
                                                                </div>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>Flipkart</td>
                                                            <td><span class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{dbd}}</span></td>
                                                            <td>{{tp}}</td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                {{stts}}
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>-</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        {% endfor %}
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        </form>
```

I want something like:

```
<input name="scan_order" id="scan_order" type="text" placeholder="Scan" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
```

and in views:

```
elif request.method == 'POST' and 'scan_order' in request.POST:
## Do Something
```

Question is: Can i do it with my existing form? Or is there another method to pass data to my views.py?