# How to Input type text with formaction in django?

Tags: python, html, django

In HTML can input type text have a `formaction=""` attribute?
I mean a submit button can have a separate `formaction` like: [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_formaction.asp)

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
  <input type="submit" formaction="demo_admin.asp" value="Submit as admin">
</form>
```

So can i use `formaction` attribute  with `type="text"`? Like:

```
<form action="{% url 'packOrders' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="lname" formaction="{% url 'login' %}">
</form>
```

What I am trying to do is to make box with text input so that when i input some text and press enter, it should not call the main form's action. Instead should pass the value to a different action defined in `formaction`.

This is similar like [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32457554/django-form-action-on-text-input-scan) but different

Comment: you can put your submit button out of form tag for this functionality

Comment: How can i do that? can you elaborate a little more?